# Use engagement split and new version in Journey Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm new with MC. I have two questions about Journey Builder

[image]

- I have a journey builder like the image above. The engagement split metric is "opens". I expected if I clicked to "Duc email" to open it, then it would send the "MC connect test" email. I did click into the email (in my spam box) but it didn't send the next email. I wonder why? The flow said it wasn't opened.
- I also made a new version based on an older version and activated it. But it seemed it couldn't send the emails (0 entries)?? The setting of this journey is same like the first one. I don't know which issues I am facing
  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Journey Builder is not reactive, it's time-based.

After the first Email you should add **Wait Activity** for some time - ideally at least an hour, before checking if the Email was opened / clicked.

On the second point - Journey entry depends on your **Journey Settings** for Contacts, if they can enter while they're still in the older version of the Journey or not.

Make sure the setting is allowing existing Contacts to enter at any time if you're using the same DE and are want to re-inject everyone.

Comment: Hi @Rain , thank you for your answer. In the 2nd question, I went to Journey setting and set contacts entry equals "re-entry anytime" and it worked.
In the 1st question, I added "wait for duration" in 45 mins before engagement split and it was stuck or something. It didn't work. It supposed to work well with any specific time

Comment: I confirmed @Rain was right. I added "wait for duration" in 1 hour before the engagement split (check email opening) and received the 2nd email in no time. I didn't even wait for 1 hour to receive the 2nd email.  
So another question is why we need to add a **Wait Activity**. As I understand the activity has nothing to do in the flow?